# Are the PicoScope 2000 series capable of capturing long signals at high sampling rates?

Tags: oscilloscope, ultrasound, datalogger

I need a device to record voltage signals captured with an ultrasonic sensor for at least 1-2 minutes hopefully, 12 bit. The signals are around 100 kHz and of very low voltage, mV range. I ran into the PicoScope 2000 series devices, in particular the PicoScope 2048B and it seems to fit my requirements. (https://fi.farnell.com/pico-technology/picoscope-2408b/oscilloscope-usb-4-ch-100mhz-1gsps/dp/2535479) 100 MHz bandwidth, 1 GHz sampling rate, 128 MS of deep memory and USB connectivity. I was wondering if anyone has worked with a similar PicoScope model for collecting large signals and if they've had a satisfactory experience.

Thank you!

Comment: What does the product brochure state?

Comment: Have you calculated the memory need for 12 bits x 100 kHz x 2 minutes?

Comment: 120,000,000 / 100,000 = 120 seconds...and then halve that at minimum for Nyquist. If you have a 200kHz signal you need to sample at least as fast as 2x that fast, preferably 4x or even 8x.